# The conditional probability of throwing 6 in four attempts, given that the first attempt is not 6

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> What is the probabilty that, if the first throw of a dice is $ \lnot 6 $, do 6 after 4 throws.

Can you check me if my solution is right?

My answer:

$ A = \text{ first  throw  }\lnot 6 \space \rightarrow P(A) = \frac{5}{6}$

B = need 4 throws for do 6 $ \rightarrow P(B) = 1-(\frac{1}{6}*4) = \frac{1}{3} $

P(B|A) is the question.

It's evident that if B happens $\rightarrow$ A happens so  $A \supset B$ and $A \cap B = B$

$$
P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(B)}{P(A)}= 0.4
$$

Comment: What value takes $P(B)$ if $4$ is replaced by e.g. $7$?

Comment: By $\neg6$ you mean "not a $6$"? What is meant by "do $6$ after $4$ throws"? Is the die $6$-sided and fair?

Answer (score 2):

if first throw is given as not 6 then it does not contribute to the probability of a 6 in 4 throws.

So the question can be changed to probability of a 6 in 3 throws.

which is 1 - (5/6 * 5/6 * 5/6) = 91/216 = 0.4213